# create new milestone using github api - responses with not found

Tags: jquery, github, http-post

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:   "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url:    "https://api.github.com/repos/"+name+"/milestones" ,
    data:   { title:milestone_val , state:"open", description:"test"} ,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    error: function(data) {
        milestone_val = null;
        console.log("error");
    },

    async:   false
});
```

always responses error.

```
response :
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "http://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide the full code, this is just a wild guess, but I think that the variable `name` only contains the name of the repository (eg. **libgit2sharp**).

If that's the case, you should value it so that it is prefixed with the name of the user or organization (eg. **libgit2/libgit2sharp**).

As an example, this url https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2sharp/milestones fails and returns the same error you encountered.

This one https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2sharp/milestones works returning the current open milestone.

**Note:** The provided examples above leverage the GET api, but the same issue would occur with a POST request.

Comment: name contains 'user/repo'

Comment: Does it actually contain 'user/repo' (because in this case this wouldn't work as https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo points to no valid repository :) ) Or do you mean that `name` contains a string that's a concatenation of a username, a forward slash and a repository name? In that last case, can you access in a browser the high-level JSON view of the url https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}? Can you share its name or is this a private repository?

Comment: There might be another reasons this is failing: GitHub returns a 404 instead of 401 for unauthorized requests against private repositories, so that the info that a repository like that is even there. See this for details: http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication